# SQL - text+value to 1 coulm, how?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i make this?
From table A's Value with prefix to table B's

Table A

```
+-------+-------+----+
| Name  | Value | ID |
+-------+-------+----+
| name1 |  123  |  1 |
+-------+-------+----+
```

Table B

```
+--------------------+------+
|    textandvalue    | BID  |
+--------------------+------+
| 'any text'+A.Value | A.ID |
+--------------------+------+
```

How can i add to table B my text, and the value?

Comment: Do you want an insert? an update?

Comment: Insert, i'm insert a lot column at same time, but i need to add the to column a URL, http://.../?="and here the value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general form for this is `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into b(textandvalue, BID)
    select concat('any text', value), id
    from a;
```

A `values` statement is not needed for this type of `insert`.  Mixing `values` and `select` in `insert` statements usually leads to some form of confusion.

By the way, if you don't need another table and just want to see the values (or perhaps as a subquery), you can just use the `select` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [mySQL CONCAT() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), for example:

```
INSERT INTO table_b (textandvalue, BID) VALUES ((SELECT CONCAT('http://www.somewebsite.com/?=', Value) FROM table_a), (SELECT ID FROM table_a))
```